# Updating multiple lines at once in d3.js multi-series chart

Tags: d3.js, dynamic, selection

I want to create a multi-series chart where lines correspond to repeated measurements data of patients. Patients are grouped into teams of clinicians and I want a dropdown menu to govern which team's patients are shown.

The graph is initialised with no data. Then when you select teams, the lines are appended to the screen but the lines associated with older teams are not removed. Below is a code chunk containing the update function–I think but probably not–in line with the general update pattern advocated by Bostock.

Related stackoverflow questions seem to address this issue, but for cases when filter is about a single line, not a group of lines.

```
function update(data) {
 var u = svg
    .append("g")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(data)

  u.enter()
   .append("path")
   .attr("class", "line")
   .attr("stroke", "grey")
   .attr("fill", "none")
   .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
   .attr("d",function(d) { return line(d.values) });

     u.exit().remove() 

  }
```

Here a link to a plunk containing my hack at [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VilgrUBSQauhxQLgDOpL?p=preview)

I don't understand what happens in the update pattern when it is about multiple lines. How do I tell d3.js to remove the lines that were previously selected but no longer?